# Java JDBC понимание

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

У меня есть вопрос на понимание JDBC.

Statement: можно ли через один Statement прогонять следующий запрос не закрывая предыдущий.

Comment: А ты попробуй. создаёшь один, создаёшь второй, выполняешь второй, выполняешь первый, если хочешь.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но делать этого не стоит.

(выдержка из java-doc`ов)

```
/**
 * <P>The object used for executing a static SQL statement
 * and returning the results it produces.
 * <P>
 * By default, only one <code>ResultSet</code> object per <code>Statement</code>
 * object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one
 * <code>ResultSet</code> object is interleaved
 * with the reading of another, each must have been generated by
 * different <code>Statement</code> objects. All execution methods in the
 * <code>Statement</code> interface implicitly close a statment's current
 * <code>ResultSet</code> object if an open one exists.
 *
 * @see Connection#createStatement
 * @see ResultSet
 */
   public interface Statement extends Wrapper, AutoCloseable {
```

Но если речь идет только о корректной работе с ресурсами, тогда нужно смотреть в сторону использования [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)